# How to make element not have hover over border/outline?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of 50% width elements that are next to each other, and I want to give each of them a 20px white border to separate them, the reason for this is that I have a responsive layout and I always want there to be 40px white space in between the elements.

I have a hover effect over them too, but when you use border on the main element, when you hover over the border or outline, you trigger the hover effect, which I don't want.

http://jsfiddle.net/keleturner/6PqJt/
Try hovering on the red border and outline (outline you need to hover in between the two blocks to trigger hover).

The only solution I found was to add a new element to wrap everything inside the  `.main` and give it a border there,  but that is very non-semantic and having to extra markup for something like this doesn't seem right.

Comment: Margin was invented to space elements. You should not use the border or outline for that.

Comment: But fixed margin in pixels and 50% width do not go together. As I explained it is a responsive width, but the whitespace should be the same throughout, is there no other way?

Comment: Margin and fixed pixels **can** go together is you use the appropriate margins for each div (`nth-of-type` or `nth-child` can help here). Fundamentally, I think your layout approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
.main:hover .inside { background: blue; }
```

is wrong, it should be

```
.main .inside:hover { background: blue; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6PqJt/5/ EDIT - updated fiddle to fix bottom .main - also added some css to fix the hover of the second one

Comment: That won't work unfortunately, it has to be .main:hover, I simplified the html to show the issue, but I can't change that part, is there no other way?

Comment: Well if you specify :hover on .main, then the WHOLE of .main will respond to the :hover css.

EDIT - if your aim is to keep 40px padding whilst it's responsive, why don't you just change what happens to the separate divs at different resolutions?